# Simpler Notation or Way to do If Else in C#

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I admire the simplicity of `? : operator` like

```
bool b;
int x,y,z;

x = b ? y : z;
```

to replace

```
if(b)
  x = y;
else
  x = z;
```

So I wonder is there some simpler notation or way do `if/else` in more compicated expression , or do something a bit like lambda and I can write more complicated actions in lamda?

For example maybe some imaginary notation like  `@ $`

to do

```
x = b @ { z*=3.14; return y; }   //if b true do z*=3.14 and x = y
      $ { y-= 100; return z; }   //if b false do y-=100 and x = z
```

or

```
bool b , c
int[] count = new[] {0, 0, 0};

b @ count[0]++ //if b is true do count[0]++ 
  $ c @ count[1]++  //if b is false c is true do count[1]++ 
      $ count[2]++;  //if b,c all false do count[2]++
```

I think the if/else notation is quite brief, however I'll be glad to know if there's a simpler way.

I hope the way can be used under C# 5.0, but in C# 6.0 is welcomed ,too.

Comment: You *can* nest the ternary operator ?:... but it would pose problems in maintaining it because it's too easy to misread.

Comment: brevity != better.

Comment: It is important to write code that can be easily read and maintained by you or somebody inheriting your work - it certainly adds more value than clever shorthand notations.

Comment: I copy paste an opinion by another one here----This certainly works and with simple expressions it can be easier to read, however, for more compound statements involving function calls etc, you may want to opt for capturing and storing results in an instance variable first.

Comment: ----The reason for this is that no symbol is created in the symbol table when using compound statements involving function calls as parameters. In the end, the compiler will optimize these extra placeholder variables out anyways, and in the meantime you would now have a symbol that you can look at in the debugger without needing print out statements in your code.

Comment: TerseCode.IsReadable && TerseCode.IsMaintainable ? UseIt() : SpellItOut();

Comment: Your question is still a duplicate. Please stop deleting [your poorly-researched question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42080241/to-replace-if-else) only to post essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a generic extension method with lambdas:

```
public static T IIf<T>(this bool valueToCheck, Func<T> ifTrue, Func<T> ifFalse)
{
    return valueToCheck ? ifTrue() : ifFalse();
}
```

And call them like this:

```
bool flag = ComputeABoolean();
var result = flag.IIf(() => { Console.WriteLine("Yeah this is sort of crazy"); return "Value was true."; },
                      () => { Console.WriteLine("But it does work."); return "value was false";});
```

This allows complex expressions, side effects, etc.

Personally, I don't think I would ever do this.

Comment: *"Personally, I don't think I would ever do this. "* Good point - I never really liked this syntax in vba/vb so I'm not gonna introduce it in C# myself - I mean its basically a unknown if with a different syntax. + method calls. plus lambdas. Not so much better if even compared to an if statement everybody know.